# Obtain mean vector for each parameter combination using R

Tags: r

I have a cvs file that has the following structure (minimum example):

```
ID       Variable       Vector
1         a              [0,0,0]
2         a              [1,2,3]
1         a              [1,1,2]
2         a              [1,2,3]
1         b              [0,0,0]
2         b              [1,1,1]
1         b              [0,0,1]
2         b              [3,5,7]
```

I would like to calculate the mean vector for each combination of parameters (in this case, ID and Variable). That is, I want to obtain a dataframe like the following one:

```
ID       Variable       Vector
1          a             [0.5,0.5,1]
2          a             [1,2,3]
1          b             [0,0,0.5]
2          b             [2,3,4]
```

I have generated this csv file with Python, that's why I have that structure with brackets. But I do not know how to start to do this using R. It doesn't seem to be a common data structure.

**Update:**

Vector variable structure (obtained from `dput(head(data, 8)`)

```
Vector = c("[3, 16, 14, 5, 6, 13, 17, 7, 13, 6]", 
"[7, 12, 6, 10, 6, 5, 16, 9, 19, 10]", "[4, 13, 4, 11, 6, 15, 17, 10, 12, 8]", 
"[18, 11, 16, 8, 10, 10, 7, 4, 9, 7]", "[9, 9, 10, 17, 8, 13, 3, 13, 8, 10]", 
"[17, 12, 7, 13, 6, 13, 8, 9, 5, 10]", "[9, 6, 14, 10, 8, 4, 8, 14, 15, 12]", 
"[7, 13, 8, 10, 16, 8, 13, 13, 8, 4]")), row.names = c(NA, 8L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the 'Vector' column is a `list`, after grouping by 'ID', 'Variable', we `reduce` the 'Vector' by adding (`+`) the corresponding elements together and then divide by the total number of elements (`n()`) in that group

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- df1 %>%
     group_by(ID, Variable) %>%
      summarise(Vector =  list(reduce(Vector, `+`)/n()), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#     ID Variable Vector   
#  <dbl> <chr>    <list>   
#1     1 a        <dbl [3]>
#2     1 b        <dbl [3]>
#3     2 a        <dbl [3]>
#4     2 b        <dbl [3]>


out$Vector
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.5 0.5 1.0

#[[2]]
#[1] 0.0 0.0 0.5

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[4]]
#[1] 2 3 4
```

---

If the column 'Vector' is a `character` string, an option is to extract the numeric part into a `list`

```
library(stringr)
out <- df1 %>%
          group_by(ID, Variable) %>%
          summarise(Vector = list((str_extract_all(Vector, "\\d+") %>%
                    map(as.numeric) %>% reduce(`+`))/n()), .groups = 'drop')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), Variable = c("a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"), Vector = structure(list(c(0, 
0, 0), c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 1, 2), c(1, 2, 3), c(0, 0, 0), c(1, 1, 
1), c(0, 0, 1), c(3, 5, 7)), class = "AsIs")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I obtain this error "Error in .x + .y : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: @pyring I was assuming that you have a `list` column.  Can you show the `str(yourdf)`.  If it s a string column, then it won't work

Comment: @pyring Or you can show structure of your dataset with `dput` i.e. `dput(head(yourdf, 8))` this would help me in testing

Comment: indeed, each vector-object is labeled as chr

Comment: @pyring Do you have a structure like `"[0,0,0]"`

Comment: @pyring Please check my update.  It should work if the structure is what I mentioned

Comment: thanks @akrun, I have updated the question to show some info about the structure of the Vector variable. Indeed there are not structures containing all ceros.

Comment: @pyring I tested your updated input.  It is working with the update in my post.  Please check